# Spring unit test not getting the updated values from database

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, junit, spring-jdbc

I have simple spring configuration using plain spring jdbc with dao in place. 
I have added a test case for the dao layer which does the following functionality.
- Get the settings
- test the number of records and the values
- Update the settings with new values
- test the updated values.

I am not able to assert the values with the updated, below is the error I am getting. Not sure what is wrong.

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.386 sec <<< FAILURE!
updateTest(com.sims.service.SettingsServiceTests)  Time elapsed: 1.086 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[My Org]> but was:<[New Org1]>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.abc.service.SettingsServiceTests.updateTest(SettingsServiceTests.java:57)
```

Can any one let me know what is wrong in the configuration. I have added applicationContext.xml, Dao and unit test for dao.

### applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- import the dataSource definition -->
<import resource="datasource-config.xml" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/data-access.properties"
    system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />

<tx:annotation-driven />


<!-- Transaction manager for a single JDBC DataSource (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
```

### SettingsDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class SettingsDaoImpl extends BaseDao{

private static final class SettingMapper implements RowMapper<Settings> {

    public SettingMapper() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Settings mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        final Settings settings= new Settings();

        settings.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
        settings.setOrgName(rs.getString("org_name"));
        settings.setOrgAddress(rs.getString("org_address"));
        settings.setOrgPhone(rs.getString("org_phone"));
        settings.setLanguage(rs.getString("language"));
        settings.setTimeZone(rs.getString("time_zone"));
        settings.setCountry(rs.getString("country"));
        settings.setCurrencyType(rs.getString("currency"));

        return settings;
    }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Settings getSettings(){
    final String sql = "select * from settings";
    final Settings student = new Settings();

    final SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(
            student);

    final List<Settings> result = this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(
            sql, paramSource, new SettingMapper());

    if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
        return result.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Settings saveSetting(Settings settings) {
    Settings tSettings = null;
    if (settings.isNew()) {
        tSettings = insert(settings);
    } else {
        tSettings = update(settings);
    }

    return tSettings;
}


public Settings insert(Settings settings){
    final String sql = "insert into settings (org_name, org_address, org_phone, language, time_zone, country, currency) "
    +" values (:orgName, :orgAddress, :orgPhone, :language, :timeZone, :country, :currency)";
    final GeneratedKeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    final String[] keyColumnNames = { "id" };

    final SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(
            settings);

    final int count = this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(sql,
            paramSource, generatedKeyHolder, keyColumnNames);

    settings.setId(generatedKeyHolder.getKey().longValue());
    return settings;
}

public Settings update(final Settings settings) throws DataAccessException {
        final StringBuilder updateClause = new StringBuilder();
        SettingDb.getUpdateSql(updateClause);
        final String sql = "update settings set org_name:=orgName, org_address:= orgAddress, " +
        org_phone:=orgPhone, language:=language, time_zone:=timeZone, country:=country, currency:=currency where id=:id";

        final GeneratedKeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        final String[] keyColumnNames = { "id" };

        final SqlParameterSource paramSource = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(
                settings);

        final int count = this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(sql,
                paramSource, generatedKeyHolder, keyColumnNames);

        return settings;
}

}
```

---

### SettingsDAOTests.java

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=true)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SettingsDAOTests {

@Autowired
private SettingsDaoImpl settingsDaoImpl;

@Test
public void testSettings(){

    Settings settings = settingsDaoImpl.getSettings();
    Assert.assertNotNull(settings);

    String orgName = "New Org";
    String orgAddress = "New Org Ad";
    String phoneNumber = "Ph1";
    String language = "Hindi";
    String timeZone = "GMT";
    String country = "US";
    String currency = "Dollar";

    settings.setCountry(country);
    settings.setOrgAddress(orgAddress);
    settings.setOrgName(orgName);
    settings.setOrgPhone(phoneNumber);
    settings.setLanguage(language);
    settings.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    settings.setCurrencyType(currency);

    settingsDaoImpl.saveSetting(settings);

    Settings settings1 = settingsDaoImpl.getSettings();

    Assert.assertEquals(orgName, settings1.getOrgName());
    Assert.assertEquals(orgAddress, settings1.getOrgAddress());
    Assert.assertEquals(phoneNumber, settings1.getOrgPhone());
    Assert.assertEquals(timeZone, settings1.getTimeZone());
    Assert.assertEquals(country, settings1.getCountry());
    Assert.assertEquals(currency, settings1.getCurrencyType());

    String orgName1 = "New Org1";
    String orgAddress1 = "New Org Ad1";
    String phoneNumber1 = "Ph11";
    String language1 = "Hindi1";
    String timeZone1 = "GMT1";
    String country1 = "US1";
    String currency1 = "Dollar1";

    settings.setCountry(country1);
    settings.setOrgAddress(orgAddress1);
    settings.setOrgName(orgName1);
    settings.setOrgPhone(phoneNumber1);
    settings.setLanguage(language1);
    settings.setTimeZone(timeZone1);
    settings.setCurrencyType(currency1);

    settingsDaoImpl.saveSetting(settings);

    Settings settings2 = settingsDaoImpl.getSettings();

    Assert.assertEquals(orgName, settings2.getOrgName());
    Assert.assertEquals(orgAddress, settings2.getOrgAddress());
    Assert.assertEquals(phoneNumber, settings2.getOrgPhone());
    Assert.assertEquals(timeZone, settings2.getTimeZone());
    Assert.assertEquals(country, settings2.getCountry());
    Assert.assertEquals(currency, settings2.getCurrencyType());
}
}
```

Comment: I am answering as I cannot comment. I would suggest you to refer the following link:-
[http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-example-with-jdbc](http://www.journaldev.com/2603/spring-transaction-management-example-with-jdbc) **what I feel you are getting some sort of exception, put a try catch block while calling database query. try looking deep into stack trace you will find your solution.**

Answer (score 0):

Spring will rollback the DB updates as you are using:

```
defaultRollback=true
```

Comment: From my understanding with "defaultRollback=true", test framework will roll back all the transactions for each test method. In my case, with the test method I am doing get the record (settingsDaoImpl.getSettings()), update the record (settingsDaoImpl.saveSetting(settings)), and get the values of the record again (settingsDaoImpl.getSettings()), my test expects to the updated values in the last get but we are getting still old values. Any thought. I appreciate your help.

Comment: BTW, i tried with "defaultRollback=false", but that does not help.

Comment: Can any one please help me on this? what am I doing wrong?